# arrangement of images using cakephp 2.0 and jquery

Tags: jquery, image, cakephp

Please look at [this](https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/106316055239076667927/albums/5704487469943215585) and tell me how I go about arranging photos dynamically like this using cakephp and jquery.

I am after the logic rather than the actual code but examples would be nice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

http://masonry.desandro.com/

or

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/